# Why is the return is List<char>?

Tags: c#, list, contains

I am trying to pull file names that match the substring using "contains" method. However, return seem to be `List<char>` but I expect `List<string>`.

```
private void readAllAttribues()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(attribute_file))
    {
        //List<string> AllLines = new List<string>();
        List<FileNameAttributeList> AllAttributes = new List<FileNameAttributeList>();

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            FileNameAttributeList Attributes = new FileNameAttributeList();
            Attributes ImageAttributes = new Attributes();
            Point XY = new Point();
            string lineItem = reader.ReadLine();
            //AllLines.Add(lineItem);
            var values = lineItem.Split(',');

            Attributes.ImageFileName = values[1];
            XY.X = Convert.ToInt16(values[3]);
            XY.Y = Convert.ToInt16(values[4]);
            ImageAttributes.Location = XY;
            ImageAttributes.Radius = Convert.ToInt16(values[5]);
            ImageAttributes.Area = Convert.ToInt16(values[6]);
            AllAttributes.Add(Attributes);
        }
        List<string> unique_raw_filenames = AllAttributes.Where(x => x.ImageFileName.Contains(@"non")).FirstOrDefault().ImageFileName.ToList();
        List<string>var unique_reference_filenames = AllAttributes.Where(x => x.ImageFileName.Contains(@"ref")).FirstOrDefault().ImageFileName.ToList();


        foreach (var unique_raw_filename in unique_raw_filenames)
        {
            var raw_attributes = AllAttributes.Where(x => x.ImageFileName == unique_raw_filename).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Datatype class

```
public class FileNameAttributeList
        {   // Do not change the order
            public string ImageFileName { get; set; }
            public List<Attributes> Attributes { get; set; }

            public FileNameAttributeList()
            {
                Attributes = new List<Attributes>();
            }
        }
```

Why is FirstOrDefault() does not work ? (It returns `List<char>` but I am expecting `List<string>` and fails.

Comment: Why do you expect `x.ToList()`, where `x` is `String`, to produce `List<String>`?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` is applied to the result of the `Where` query, which is presumably an enumerable. You're thus taking only the *first* object's `ImageFileName` (presumably a string), and then casting that string `ToList` will create a list of its characters.

Comment: It comes down to you applying ToList() to the wrong thing. You apply it to a string, rather then ... whatever you expected the thing to be at that time. The Property names are a giveaway - `ImageFileName`sounds like it is one Filename, not a colleciton of FileNames. A `string` rather then a `List<string>` or `string[]` or whatever else you expected here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```cs
List<string> unique_raw_filenames = AllAttributes.Where(x => x.ImageFileName.Contains(@"non")).FirstOrDefault().ImageFileName.ToList();
```

FirstOrDefault() returns the first, or default, FileNameAttributeList from the list AllAttributes where the ImageFileName contains the text `non`.
Calling ToList() on the ImageFileName then converts the string value into a list of chars because string is a collection of char.

I think that what you are intending can be achieved by switching out `FirstOrDefault` to `Select`. [`Select`](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-projection-operators) allows you to map one value onto another.

So your code could look like this instead.

```cs
List<string> unique_raw_filenames = AllAttributes.Where(x => x.ImageFileName.Contains(@"non")).Select(x => x.ImageFileName).ToList();
```

This then gives you a list of string.

Answer (score 5):

The `ToList()` method converts collections that implement `IEnumerable<SomeType>` into lists.
Looking at the [definition](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs) of `String`, you can see that it implements `IEnumerable<Char>`, and so `ImageFileName.ToList()` in the following code will return a `List<char>`.

> AllAttributes.Where(x =>
>   x.ImageFileName.Contains(@"non")).FirstOrDefault().ImageFileName.ToList();

Although I'm guessing at what you want, it seems like you want to filter AllAttributes based on the ImageFileName, and then get a list of those file names. If that's the case, you can use something like this:

```
var unique_raw_filenames = AllAttributes.Where(x => x.ImageFileName.Contains(@"non")).Select(y=>y.ImageFileName).ToList();
```